# How do I append a list of multiple objects to the end of a file path?

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, function

I have created a for loop to create a list containing the string 'size_i' so I have size_01, size_02, size_03 etc all the way to size_84. Like:

```
def size():
    x = list()    
    for i in range(0,84):
        x = x.append('size' + str(i))
return x
```

This works fine. Now I want to save each 'size' in that list to the end of a filepath:

```
d_path = /home/Jake/Documents/sizes/size_01
       = /home/Jake/Documents/sizes/size_02
```

etc...

But for some reason I can't get it to work and I have no idea where I am going wrong! Here is my full attempt:

```
import os

def size():
    d_path = '/home/Jake/Documents/sizes'
    x = list()
    for i in range(0,84):
        x = x.append('size_' + str(i))
        p = os.path.join(d_path,x)
    return p
```

Comment: `x.append` replaces the list with `None`, as `append` doesn't return anything. Also, the loop seems completely wrong - shouldn't you be returning a list, and only using the last item in `x` each time?

Comment: instead of `x.append..` try this: `s='size_'+str(i)`, `x.append(s)`, `p=os.path.join(d_path,s)`

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand of the question, you are writing your function wrong. `x.append('size_' + str(i))` returns `None`, so basically you were replacing x with `None` in `x = x.append('size_' + str(i))` which was giving an error when you were trying to join.
Your current function is returning the last name that you are trying to create ie '/home/Jake/Documents/sizes/size_83', i believe you want to return a list containing all the names.

This will work.

```
import os

def size():
    d_path = '/home/Jake/Documents/sizes'
    x = list()
    for i in range(0,84):
        tmp = 'size_' + str(i)
        p = os.path.join(d_path,tmp)
        x.append(p)
    return x

print size()
```

Answer (score 0):

Does this work for you?

```
import os

def size():
    d_path = '/home/Jake/Documents/sizes'
    x = []
    p = []
    for i in range(0,84):
        z = 'size_' + str(i)

        x.append(z)
        p.append(d_path+z)
    return p
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
import os

def size():
    d_path = '/home/Jake/Documents/sizes'
    x = list()
    for i in range(0,84):
        x.append(os.path.join(d_path,'size_' + str(i)))
    return x
```

Answer (score 0):

The function append in class list doesn't return a 
significant value.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import os

def size():
    d_path = '/home/Jake/Documents/sizes'
    x = []
    p=[]
    for i in range(0,84):
        x.append('size_{:02}'.format(i))
        p.append(os.path.join(d_path,x[i]))
    return p

print size()
```

Comment: print needs parentheses in Python3, i.e. print(size())

Comment: I know, but the tag says `python-2.7`.

Answer (score 0):

Some of these answers are unnecessarily long and complex, but may more be insightful about what's going on than the following snippets:

**Clear Approach**

```
path_root = "/home/Jake/Documents/sizes"

sizes = ["size_%d" % i for i in range(84)]
paths = [os.path.join(path_root, s) for s in sizes]

print(paths)
```

**Alternative Approach**

```
path_root = "/home/Jake/Documents/sizes"

paths = [os.path.join(path_root, "size_%d" % i) for i in range(84)]

print(paths)
```

Some notes:

- Both approaches use list comprehensions
- When the lower bound of range is zero, it can be omitted
- Both approaches use the `%` sign printf-style string formatting operator
- If you want leading zeros for single digit numbers like your comments (but not your code) suggest, you can replace `"size_%d"` with `"size_%02d"`